# error de selección en input de tipo radio

Tags: html5, css3, input, radiobutton, radiogroup

Me sucede que al ocultar los input de tipo radio para aplicarle estilos deja de funcionar la segunda columna de opciones al hacerles click. a la segunda columna se le aplican los estilos pero no reaccionan al click.
alguien sabe de que forma se pueden distribuir los ? sospecho que el error está ahi pero ya busqué como distribuirlos y nada me estaría funcionando

```
     <label id="services-label" >Services of interest: </label>
     <label id="services-label" >Asesoría|Creación </label>
     <label>  <input name="identidad" value="Identidad-asesoria" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" ><i></i> 
       <input name="identidad" value="Identidad-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox">Identidad de marca<i></i> </label>
     <label> <input name="Estrategia" value="Estrategia-asesoria" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" ><i></i>
       <input name="Estrategia" value="Estrategia-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" > Estrategia de contenidos <i></i> </label>
     <label> <input name="Creacion" value="Creación-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" ><i></i>
     <input name="Creacion" value="Creación-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" >  Creación de contenido.<i></i> </label>
   </div>


.form-group input[type=radio] {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}
.form-group input[type=radio] {
position: relative;
 margin-left: -10px;
 padding-left:0px;
.form-group input + i{
background: #f0f0f0;
border:1px solid red;
float: left;
left: 0;
top: 2px;
margin-left:15px ;
position: relative;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
border-radius: 100%;
left: 5px;
}
.form-group .input-checkbox + i:before{
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 5px;
 width: 5px;
 background: red;
 border-radius: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
 background:red;
 transition: all 0.25s ease;
 transform: scale(0)  ;
 opacity: 0;  
}
.form-group .input-checkbox:checked + i:before{
 transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 1;
}

.form-group:hover .input-checkbox:not(:checked) + i{
 background:whitesmoke;
}
```

Comment: No olvides realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos errores que se debe corregir:

El contenedor padre de los input: o puede que copiaste mal para pegar aquí o se te olvidó definir en to HTML (porque hay una etiqueta div cerrada pero no una abierta).

La clase `.form-group input[type=radio]` no tiene cierre de llave.

Quedaría bien así:

```css
            
.form-group input[type=radio] { 
visibility: hidden; 
position: absolute; 
right: 0; 
} 

.form-group input[type=radio] { 
position: relative; 
margin-left: -10px; 
padding-left:0px; 


.form-group input + i{ 
background: #f0f0f0; 
border:1px solid red; 
float: left; 
left: 0; 
top: 2px; 
margin-left:15px ; 
position: relative; 
height: 15px; 
width: 15px;
border-radius: 100%; 
left: 5px; 
} 

.form-group .input-checkbox + i:before{ 
content: ''; 
display: block; 
height: 5px;
width: 5px; 
background: red; 
border-radius: 100%;
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; 
top: 5px; 
left: 5px;
background:red;
transition: all 0.25s ease; 
transform: scale(0) ; 
opacity: 0; 
} 

.form-group .input-checkbox:checked + i:before{ 
transform: scale(1);
opacity: 1; 
} 

.form-group:hover .input-checkbox:not(:checked) + i{ 
background:whitesmoke; 
}
```

```html
            
<div class="" id="">
    
    <label id="services-label" >Services of interest: </label> 
    <label id="services-label" >Asesoría|Creación </label>
    
    <label>
        <input name="identidad" value="Identidad-asesoria" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" ><i></i> 
        <input name="identidad" value="Identidad-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox">Identidad de marca<i></i> 
    </label> 
    
    <label> 
        <input name="Estrategia" value="Estrategia-asesoria" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" ><i></i> 
        <input name="Estrategia" value="Estrategia-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" > Estrategia de contenidos <i></i> 
    </label> 
    
    <label> 
        <input name="Creacion" value="Creación-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" ><i></i> 
        <input name="Creacion" value="Creación-creacion" type="radio" class="input-checkbox" > Creación de contenido.<i></i> 
    </label> 

</div>
```

Aparte de esto, en los `label` hay etiqueta `i` vacíos (pero dedusco que están esperando su contenido).

Comment: si! fue error mio al copiarlo acá, pero de todas maneras al aplicarle los estilos la segunda columna de inputs no reacciona al click, solo la primera. se muestran pero al clickear cualquiera de los dos solo se marcan las casillas de la primer columna

Comment: Con esta respuesta funciona bien. Revisaste?

Comment: si, lo revisé varias veces y aun no devuelve el punto rojo a los inputs de la segunda columna, solo a los de la primera. sin los estilos funciona perfectamente pero al aplicarlos deja de funcionar